# Angular : How to redirect to a static unsupported.html page if the current browser is Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, browser

I put this code inside a `<script>` in `index.html`. This seems to be working for IE versions 10 upwards.

```
const isIE = /msie\s|trident/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
if (isIE) {
  window.location.href = "./unsupported.html";
}
```

But for versions 8 and 9 I just get a blank page.

Is there a way to make it work for older IE versions as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't work in IE 8~9 because `const` is only supported by IE 11. You can check the [browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility).

I suggest you to use `var` instead of `const` which is compatible with IE 8~11:

```
var isIE = /msie\s|trident/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
if (isIE) {
  window.location.href = "./unsupported.html";
}
```

Test Result:

[image]